# How to send push notification from server to iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

Can anyone provide some links of some tutorials or some code that demonstrates sending push notification from server to iOS app?

Comment: No. No. Why do not you use Google for that? *People here are not free to Spoon Feed!!*

Answer (score 1):

For PHP (LAMP), there's [Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/). You can host it yourself.

There are many services, such as [Parse](https://www.parse.com/products/push), that host the server for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice tutorial for push notification

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1